# Pre-composed email which has weblink

Tags: html, email

I have a requirement to open gmail or lotus notes email client on a click of a button. I have created a html reference tab and it works if there are no link but my requirement is to open a precompose email which has link for few documents along with instructions.

Code given below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mailBackground">
        <span class="heading">
Dear user,
            <br/>
        </span>
        <span id="authoriserName" class="body">
            <p> Please use below steps to open google url:</p>
        </span>
        <form>
            <a href="mailto:example@google.com?subject=Test+Subject&cc=example@google.com&body=Hi%20%3Cuser%3E%2C%0D%0A%3Cp%3EThank%20you%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%3EWhat%20does%20that%20mean%3F%20%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%3EClick%20on%20Google%20Drive%20link%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F%22%3EGoogle%3C%2Fa%3E%20%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cb%3EWhat%20you%20need%20to%20do%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cul%20type%3D%22disc%22%3E%0D%0A%3Cli%3ELine%201%20%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ful%3E%0D%0ARegards%2C%3Cbr%3E%0D%0AJack"
                onclick="javascript:window.location.href='mailto:example@google.com?subject=Test+Subject&cc=example@google.com&body=Hi%20%3Cuser%3E%2C%0D%0A%3Cp%3EThank%20you%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%3EWhat%20does%20that%20mean%3F%20%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%3EClick%20on%20Google%20Drive%20link%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F%22%3EGoogle%3C%2Fa%3E%20%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cb%3EWhat%20you%20need%20to%20do%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cul%20type%3D%22disc%22%3E%0D%0A%3Cli%3ELine%201%20%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ful%3E%0D%0ARegards%2C%3Cbr%3E%0D%0AJack'; return false;"
                class="Button" type="button" value="Button">Button</a>
        </form>
        <span class="labelColor body">
            <br/>Regards,
            <br/>Jack
        </span>
        <br/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output comes like below when I click on the Button.

```
Hi <user>,
<p>Thank you</p>
<p>What does that mean? </p>
<p>Click on Google Drive link <a href="https://google.com/">Google</a> </p>
</p><b>What you need to do</b></p>
<ul type="disc">
<li>Line 1 </li>
</ul>
Regards,<br>
Jack
```

Please let me how to put it in a right format so that when the user click on the link the precomposed email should have the link added without looking as cloud.

Regards,
Naresh